# MySQL, PHP - Post "empty"

Tags: php, html, mysql

Code for demonstration:

#### wrong:

```
 if ($_POST['a125']>-1){$a125 = -1*$_POST['a125'];}else{$a125 = "";}
```

#### wrong2:

```
if ($_POST['a125']>-1){$a125 = -1*$_POST['a125'];}else{$a125 = $_POST['a125'];}
```

#### What would I like to do?

- I have a number
- If this number bigger than `-1`, I would like it to make that a negative number (*that's easy*)
- *BUT* if this number in the input area is `empty`, my codes returns a zero value, but I would like to leave it empty.

This code part of an audiogram. My problem is, if I leave the input area empty, I do not want to make a point on my graph, but if my code makes `0` from my `empty` value, that will appear on my graph.

#### Results:

- My code result example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GkO4.jpg
- MySQL posted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXl8h.jpg

Comment: $_POST does not automatically retrieve data from database for you. From the code that you have provided, it seems like that is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with check, that a125 key is not empty. You can not use empty() function here, becase it will skip value: 0.

```
If (strlen(trim($_POST['a125']))) > 0) {
    // you have some value there
    if ($_POST['a125']>-1){$a125 = -1*$_POST['a125'];}
}
```